# git - keeping multiple location in sync

Tags: git, github, synchronization, branch

I have a master and a branch repo in github and i've been working on the project in multiple locations, ie. work and home. The local repos at work are fine because this is where i created the branch.

What i want to do is get my local repo at home to the same point. ie. sync to the remote repo that has the new branch on it.

I have pulled the remote repo down to my local and i get all the right commits. The only problem is, I'm not sure how i get the local repo to point to the new branch.

If i create a branch with the same name as that on the remote, the local adds the branch to (HEAD -> master) line, so the commits above this are not available.

[image]

How do i create a branch (pro-rata-TSR) that i can switch to that will have all the commits from origin/pro-rata-TSR from the remote?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a "local" branch of origin/pro-rata-TSR? - i.e. `git checkout -b pro-rata-TSR origin/pro-rata-TSR`? or do I not quite understand your question? (and run `git fetch` first to get the latest updates)

Comment: @code_fodder This is exactly what I needed. Your commands worked, if you make it an answer I can upvote it.

Comment: thanks dude, also, if you don't know it already, try this log command: `git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline` to produce a nice graphical representation of your branches/commits (you can setup an alias for it), personally - I find it much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want a "local" branch of origin/pro-rata-TSR.

Use the following commands:

- Download any commits, branches/tags from the remote repo and add them
  to your local repo (but does not change the state of your repo (i.e.
  does not merge anything or change your files):

  `git fetch`

  You don't have to do this step, but its often worth doing just to make sure you get the latest changes from the remote.
- Checkout the remote branch "origin/pro-rata-TSR" into a local
  branch called "pro-rata-TSR" (that is the -b part of the command):

  `git checkout -b pro-rata-TSR origin/pro-rata-TSR`

  You don't really need the -b  since it will automatically assign you a local branch of the same name as the remote repo - I just like being explicit.

Check you are on that new branch by entering the command `git branch`, which will show you your local branches and highlight the one you are currently on.

To explicitly push/pull changes to/from the remote branch use: `git push/pull origin pro-rata-TSR`. I prefer this way to setting up remote tracking because it takes away any ambiguity (some time you may not have set remote tracking or are using a differently configured repo...etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `git fetch && git checkout pro-rata-TSR`.

Comment: This created a branch at the location of HEAD, when it should be at origin/pro-rata-TSR.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `git checkout pro-rata-TSR` and that will automatically checkout that branch at the position it's at, and also track the remote branch so you can push and pull to and from it.